How do I include glibc versions needed by node in my buildroot config?
I'm building a root filesystem using buildroot (running on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) for an ARM Cortex-A7 target. I'm including Node.js by selecting "[*] nodejs" in Target packages ---> Interpreter languages and scripting --->.
After successfully flashing and booting the target, I run node in /usr/bin/ and get:
/usr/bin # ./node
./node: /lib/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libstdc++.so.6: no version information available (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by ./node)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /usr/lib/libuv.so.1)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /usr/lib/libuv.so.1)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/libuv.so.1)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /usr/lib/libuv.so.1)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcares.so.2)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcares.so.2)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.36' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcares.so.2)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcares.so.2)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.3)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.3)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.3)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/libssl.so.3)
./node: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /usr/lib/libssl.so.3)

I don't see how to change the buildroot config to include the required versions of GLIBC.
The only glibc-related config options I see (in make nconfig) is "Enable compatibility shims to run on older kernels" in Toolchain --->, which I checked.

Is it possible that you first did a build without nodejs, then changed the toolchain options (to be able to enable nodejs), and didn't do a make clean?

Arnout, you called it! I think that is exactly what happened. If you create an answer I will upvote it and accept it.

You started the build of some configuration, then changed the toolchain settings, and then built again with the new settings without running make clean. You need an explicit make clean when toolchain settings are changed.

Which Buildroot version are you using? Could you provide your Buildroot .config?
I believe you're using the pre-compiled NodeJS (nodejs-bin), and it might be that it is pre-compiled for a too recent version of glibc. But that's only an hypothesis, we need more details about your setup.

Arnout--in the comment on my question--was correct when he guessed that I did a build without nodejs, then changed the toolchain options (to be able to enable nodejs), and didn't do a make clean.
